# Python: If any variable in list exists, then print the item

Tags: python, list, if-statement, any

I have a list of 0s, named "variables".  One of the 0s will become -1 spontaneously, and I'm trying to print the element which does.  For example, this is my code:

```
while True:
    if any(variables):
        print(variables[i])
```

Now, obviously "i" doesn't correlate to anything, but I'd like it to represent the index of the non-zero variable in the list "variables".  Should I enumerate?  Is there an easy way to do this with list comprehension?  Thank you!

Comment: What output do you want to see? Why not just `print(-1)`?

Comment: "One of the 0s will become -1 spontaneously" *Spontaneously?* Are you sure about that? Unless you're trying to use your system's cache/RAM as a detector for charged cosmic particles (waiting for them to flip the 10s of bits it would take to change a `-1` to a `0` in your memory), it's probably not spontaneous. You shouldn't busy-wait in a loop like this. It'll needlessly use up an entire CPU thread. There's probably some event causes that `0` to switch to `-1` . You should respond to that event when it happens.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
print(list(filter(lambda x: x==-1, variables)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to get the index? Outputting the element would be equal to just writing `print(-1)`

```
print (variables.index(-1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Printing the element would just give you `-1`.

You can loop through the list:

```
for e in variables:
    if e != 0:
        # -1 found
```

By using `print(variables.index(-1))` you can also print the spot where `-1` was found.